# How to set step for random in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have C# code with random between two double numbers:

```
Random random = new Random();
double value = random.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
```

How I can set step?

Comment: @Cyral That creates a range of *integer* values, not a range of floating point values.

Comment: So, I need that number will be with difference `0.3` every time

Comment: You mean you want to have a number and then go up or down .3 every time? That's not really random number generation. Instead you could just (randomly) generate 1 or 0 and then based on that go up or down maybe?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question and add more information, including an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
random.Next(0, (int)((maximum - minimum) / 0.3)) * 0.3 + minimum
```

Instead of trying to get a double, this first works out how many `0.3` intervals there are between `minimum` and `maximum`, picks a random integer to identify one of those steps, and then works out the value of that interval.

Hence sample output of 10 runs with `minimum = 27.0` and `maximum = 42.5`:

```
42
40.5
41.4
40.5
32.1
33
38.4
37.2
30.6
42
```